How to rename columns in sequential order, ie (1, 2, 3, etc.)
I am working with a csv file that I have loaded as a dataframe. It has 21,941 columns and is too large to open in Excel (which is how I would have normally done this). I need to rename all of these columns by assigning them IDs, which are just numbers from 1-21,941. So, 1, 2, 3, etc. The current names are all very long strings.
The first column is also blank, as that's where the rownames are. I don't know if the dataframe function takes this into account or not.
I have tried a few different things, with my current code being something like this:
library(dplyr)

data2 <- read.csv(file_name)
data2[,2:] <- rename_with(+1)

I know the +1 in the function is not correct and am unsure if I need to specify that it should not include the column where the rownames are. I've tried figuring out a function for the rename_with, but all of the examples and explanations I've seen have included making a vector, and then creating a vec <- c(vec + 1) kind of function to adapt it. However, there is no way I can manually list out every single column name for that, and am unsure if there is a function to do so or a better method that I don't know.

Numbers are not legal column names in R so while you can do it, it would make using the data afterwards more tedious.  Try names(data2)[-1] <- make.names(seq_along(data2[-1])) to give your columns legal names X1, X2 etc.

Ah, I see, thank you! I didn't realize that. Is there a way to replace the "X" with a different label? I tried experimenting with it (most recent attempt: 'names(data3)[-1] <- make.names(seq_along(data2["ASV", -1]))' but haven't had any success. I'd like to change it to read ASV1, ASV2, etc., if possible. I looked through some DataCamp tutorials, but haven't found anything useful yet. Do you have any recommendations?

Try names(data3)[-1] <- paste0("AVS", seq_along(data3[-1])).

Played with it a bit and had to take out the [-1] - I suppose the blank column was already accounted for? - but yes, it worked and I was able to do what I needed with it, thank you so much! I really appreciate the advice.

You can read in the data with the "row.names" specified as the first column. Then assign unique IDs to the names.
Example:
write.csv(mtcars, file="cars.csv")

data2 <- read.csv("cars.csv", row.names=1)
names(data2) <- seq_along(names(data2))
head(data2)


                     1 2   3   4    5     6     7 8 9 10 11
Mazda RX4         21.0 6 160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46 0 1  4  4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0 6 160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02 0 1  4  4
Datsun 710        22.8 4 108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61 1 1  4  1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4 6 258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44 1 0  3  1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7 8 360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02 0 0  3  2
Valiant           18.1 6 225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22 1 0  3  1


Whilst this does do what the OP asks, it's worth mentioning that column names starting with numbers are invalid in R and could cause unintended consequences downstream.  An alternative would be using make.names() as seen in @lotus comment on the OP.

@PGSA - That's true, but invalid doesn't me cannot do, and the OP wanted column names containing numbers only, which can be done, perhaps to save to a file for further processing outside R.

very true - I intended it as a mention not as a correction - mostly in case OP runs into a follow-up issue or if future user comes here via a search.

@PGSA I generally use the term "non-standard" rather than "invalid" when it comes to names with punctuation, starting with numbers, etc. I think, technically the correct term would be "syntactically invalid" or "non-syntactic names", but "non-standard" is more relatable for new users and gets across the message that special handling may be required without implying impossibilities.

@GregorThomas - I appreciate the correction.

If you want to keep some few words:
library(tidyverse)

# -----------------
write.csv(my_cars, file="cars.csv") # Toy data at the end
my_cars_csv <- read.csv("cars.csv", row.names=1)

colnames(my_cars_csv) <- map_chr(
  seq_along(colnames(my_cars_csv)), 
  \(x) colnames(my_cars_csv)[x] %>% 
    str_to_lower() %>% 
    stringr::word(start = 1, end = 3, sep = "\\s|\\.") %>% # number of words here
    str_replace_all("[:punct:]", "_") %>%
    paste0(., "_", str_pad(x, width = 5, pad = "0", side = "left")))

my_cars_csv <- as_tibble(my_cars_csv, rownames = "row_name")

Output:
> glimpse(my_cars_csv)
Rows: 5
Columns: 12
$ row_name                     <chr> "Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag", "Datsun 710", "Hornet 4 Drive", "Hornet Sportabout"
$ mpg_netus_orci_00001         <dbl> 21.0, 21.0, 22.8, 21.4, 18.7
$ cyl_sapien_facilisis_00002   <int> 6, 6, 4, 6, 8
$ disp_mi_vehicula_00003       <int> 160, 160, 108, 258, 360
$ hp_morbi_nam_00004           <int> 110, 110, 93, 110, 175
$ drat_sodales_sed_00005       <dbl> 3.90, 3.90, 3.85, 3.08, 3.15
$ wt_tempus_viverra_00006      <dbl> 2.620, 2.875, 2.320, 3.215, 3.440
$ qsec_quis_eros_00007         <dbl> 16.46, 17.02, 18.61, 19.44, 17.02
$ vs_tempor_nibh_00008         <int> 0, 0, 1, 1, 0
$ am_curabitur_eu_00009        <int> 1, 1, 1, 0, 0
$ gear_morbi_suspendisse_00010 <int> 4, 4, 4, 3, 3
$ carb_venenatis_purus_00011   <int> 4, 4, 1, 1, 2

No words, only ID:
colnames(my_cars_csv) <- map_chr(
  seq_along(colnames(my_cars_csv)), 
  \(x) paste0("col_", str_pad(x, width = 5, pad = "0", side = "left")))

my_cars_csv <- as_tibble(my_cars_csv, rownames = "row_name")

# Output
> glimpse(my_cars_csv)
Rows: 5
Columns: 12
$ row_name  <chr> "Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag", "Datsun 710", "Hornet 4 Drive", "Hornet Sportabout"
$ col_00001 <dbl> 21.0, 21.0, 22.8, 21.4, 18.7
$ col_00002 <int> 6, 6, 4, 6, 8
$ col_00003 <int> 160, 160, 108, 258, 360
$ col_00004 <int> 110, 110, 93, 110, 175
$ col_00005 <dbl> 3.90, 3.90, 3.85, 3.08, 3.15
$ col_00006 <dbl> 2.620, 2.875, 2.320, 3.215, 3.440
$ col_00007 <dbl> 16.46, 17.02, 18.61, 19.44, 17.02
$ col_00008 <int> 0, 0, 1, 1, 0
$ col_00009 <int> 1, 1, 1, 0, 0
$ col_00010 <int> 4, 4, 4, 3, 3
$ col_00011 <int> 4, 4, 1, 1, 2

Toy data
# set.seed(100)
# my_cars <- head(mtcars, 5)
# colnames(my_cars) <- map_chr(colnames(mtcars), \(x) paste(x, lorem::ipsum_words(10)))

my_cars <- structure(
  list(
    `mpg est nulla duis nec tempor curae tristique viverra interdum sollicitudin`         = c(21, 21, 22.8, 21.4, 18.7), 
    `cyl eget class luctus ridiculus rutrum tortor pulvinar sagittis etiam parturient`    = c(6, 6, 4, 6, 8), 
    `disp a dictumst potenti platea augue hac sagittis nec sed venenatis`                 = c(160, 160, 108, 258, 360), 
    `hp sodales himenaeos blandit consequat primis etiam sociis praesent netus faucibus`  = c(110, 110, 93, 110, 175), 
    `drat magna at suscipit massa fames primis vehicula tristique libero et`              = c(3.9, 3.9, 3.85, 3.08, 3.15), 
    `wt sociosqu sagittis sodales lacus et luctus tincidunt class inceptos rhoncus`       = c(2.62, 2.875, 2.32, 3.215, 3.44), 
    `qsec ut penatibus justo aenean magna nulla et penatibus consequat feugiat`           = c(16.46, 17.02, 18.61, 19.44, 17.02), 
    `vs dui egestas erat sagittis habitasse sociosqu pharetra venenatis bibendum pretium` = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0), 
    `am fusce nunc accumsan erat ridiculus lectus sodales fermentum pellentesque cum`     = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0), 
    `gear eu venenatis eu eget primis aliquet elementum morbi congue nascetur`            = c(4, 4, 4, 3, 3), 
    `carb pulvinar potenti feugiat sapien pretium dui risus proin massa odio`             = c(4, 4, 1, 1, 2)), 
  
  row.names = c("Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag", "Datsun 710", "Hornet 4 Drive", "Hornet Sportabout"), 
  class = "data.frame")

